# How to pass two arguments with lambda(one of argument is event)?

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

I want to change the button text on right-clicking on it. I want to do a minesweeper game.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def change_text(e,i):
    btn[i].config(text='another')

btn=[]
files=[]
for i in range(5):
    files.append("button "+str(i))

for i in range(len(files)):
    btn.append(Button(root,text=files[i],width=50))
    btn[i].pack()
    e_i=[]
    btn[i].bind('<Button-3>',lambda e, i: change_text(e,i))

root.mainloop()
```

But I have this error:

```
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'i'
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: FWIW, Why do you create a lambda just to call a different function with the same arguments in the same order? just pass that function to `bind`: `btn[i].bind('<Button-3>', change_text)`

Comment: If you also have a button calling the same function in the future, just set `e=None` in the parameter definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the Button event is the only argument that will pass in ... I think what you want is

`lambda e,i=i: change_text(e,i)` this will create a default value for i  that is equal to i  (I assume that is the expected value for i inside the lambda)

or just do like the suggestion in the comments

`btn.bind("<Button-3>",functool.partial(change_text,i=i))`

Answer (score 1):

You can't alter what is being passed to the callback, you have to make your function conform to whatever signature is being expected. In this case, it will be passed a single argument.

Since you have a free variable, define a factory function to make this easy:

```
def _make_callback(i):
    return lambda e: change_text(e, i)


....

for i in range(len(files)):
    btn.append(Button(root,text=files[i],width=50))
    btn[i].pack()
    e_i=[]
    btn[i].bind('<Button-3>', _make_callback(i))
```

As an aside, as noted in the comments, when you have a function that already takes parameters `e, i`, then `lambda e, i: change_text(e, i)` is pointless, you could have just done `change_text`. But of course, in this case, your callback only takes one parameter, but just something to keep in mind for the future...